# Experimental ideas on Bell's Theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

Looking to conduct an experiment on Bell's Theorem for a university project. I have access to a lab and ample resources. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad. In any case, best to discuss this with somebody in your department who knows what is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

In our advanced lab, I let students work with entangled photons from positron decay. The idea was described by Musser in Scientific American, I read about it here: http://www.diyphysics.com/2013/02/16/diy-wu-shaknov-experiment-cheapest-demonstration-of-quantum-entanglement/

Our lab has scintillator gamma detectors, so we can do better than with Geiger counters.

Answer (score -1):

As you are looking to conduct Bell's test, I guess you are trying to prove non-locality of entanglement.

Violation of Bell's inequality is not sufficient to prove non-locality. So, if you have time, resources, and interest, you should try to conduct experiments and scrutinize data for memory/balancing mechanism. I have scrutinized data from a couple of recent experiments and indications are such that a balancing mechanism is a real possibility as opposed to non-local phenomenon.

If you need what kind of experiments need to be conducted and how the data needs to be scrutinized, let me know and I will be happy to suggest.

However, I can not help you in conducting/setting up the experiment itself, but can specify different scenarios and what the data needs to be scrutinized for.

If you want to read my analysis, it is posted at http://vixra.org/pdf/1609.0237v7.pdf